# EF4: NavigationProperty and join: is a bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, join

I’d like to consult about a problem I have faced. I've started working on a project with a very difficult database: many tables in the DB don’t have primary keys or have multiple PKs, so I can't add correct associations for all entities in my edmx. However, for some entities it’s possible and I managed to do so. Thus, I have two entities with an association between them: Vulner and VulnerDescription. And I have a "bad" connection table for Vulners called VulnerObjectTie (with a mental FK: VulnerObjectTie.Vulner = Vulner.Id), which I can’t add correct associations to. So, I decided to do add the following LinqtoEntities query:

```
            var vulerIdList = from vulner in _businessModel.DataModel.VulverSet.Include("Descriptions")
                    join objectVulnerTie in _businessModel.DataModel.ObjectVulnerTieSet on vulner.Id equals objectVulnerTie.Vulner
                    where softwareId.Contains(objectVulnerTie.SecurityObject)
                    select vulner;
```

where description is Navigation Property for an association with the VulnerDescription table. The query works, but it does not load the Descriptions property. However, if I remove the join operator, then Descriptions are loaded correctly.

The most obvious solution for this problem is to divide one query into the next two queries:

```
            var vulerIdList = from vulner in _businessModel.DataModel.VulverSet
                    join objectVulnerTie in _businessModel.DataModel.ObjectVulnerTieSet on vulner.Id equals objectVulnerTie.Vulner
                    where softwareId.Contains(objectVulnerTie.SecurityObject)
                    select vulner.Id;

        var query = from vulner in _businessModel.DataModel.VulverSet.Include("Descriptions")
                    where vulerIdList.Contains(vulner.Id)
                    select vulner;
```

But I think it looks ugly. Can anyone suggest a more simple solution for this problem, or is it just a special feature of EF4??

thankyouplease :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known 'feature' or limitation, depending on how you look at it. Here's an interesting discussion on the topic, I'm sure there are more references to find: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d700becd-fb4e-40cd-a334-9b129344edc9/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that EF is not very well suited for "bad databases". EF (and especially all automation tools like model wizard) expects clear and correct database design.

`Include` is not supported in queries using custom joins or projections. Not supported in this case means that it is completely omitted.