# WCF, SOAP, EF, POCO

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, soap, poco

We are developing a application which should use Entity Framework and its an simple WCf Soap service (not Wcf data service). I am very confused now I have read these following posts but I don't understand where to go [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927452/ef-with-poco-wcf-wpf-reuse-poco-classes-on-client-or-use-dtos) question is almost the same but I have a restriction to use POCOs and try to avoid DTOs. Its not that big service. But the link which I mentioned ,in answer its written that  if I try to send POCO classes on wire, there will be problem with serialization.

[This](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/net/wcf-entity-framework-and-n-tier-solutions-part-2/?lang=en) post has implemented the solution which related to my problem but he did not mention anything related to serialization problem. He just changed the ProxyCreationEnabled =false which I found in many other articles as well.

But these posts are also little old, so what is the recommendation today. I have to post and get lot of Word/Excel/PDFs/Text files as well, so will it be OK to send POCO classes or it will be problem in serialization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I definitely do not agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927452/ef-with-poco-wcf-wpf-reuse-poco-classes-on-client-or-use-dtos). The answer mentioned suggests to reinvent the wheel (The answer does not even indicate why not using POCOs).

You can definitely go with POCOs, I see no reason to have serialization issues; but if you have any, you can write DTOs for these specific problematic parts and map them to POCOs in the Business layer.

It is a good practice to use POCOs as the name itself suggests; Plain Old CLR objects. Writing the same classes again instead of generating them will not have any advantage. You can simply test it.

UPDATE:

Lazy Loading: Lazy loading means fetching related objects from database whenever they are accessed. If you have already serialized and deserialized an entity (ex. you have sent the entity to client side over a wire), Lazy Loading will not work, since you will not have a proxy in the client side.

Proxy: Proxy class simply enables to communicate with DB (a very simple definition by the way). It is not possible to use an instance of Proxy in the client side; it does not make sense. Just seperate the Proxy class and POCO entities into two different DLLs and share only the POCO objects with the client. And use the proxy in the service side.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes I am thinking to test it but I read in one article about 'Disabling Lazy Loading and ProxyCreationEnabled' will solve serialization problem. But I can't find what types of problem and if I disable these will it create some other issues

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I will try to send POCO objects and will see if any problem occurs in serialization